# Use implicit differentiation to find the slope of the tangent line to the curve

Tags: calculus

4xy^3+5xy=27 Point:(3,1)

So, using Implicit Differentiation...

(4y^3+4xy^2(dy/dx))+(5y+5x(dy/dx))=0

4xy^2(dy/dx)+5x(dy/dx)=-4y^3-5y

dy/dx(4xy^2-5x)=-4y^3-5y

### dy/dx=(-4y^3-5y)/(4xy^2+5x)

Now I replace x and y in the equation with x=3 and y=1

I get 20/27, which is apparently incorrect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $(4y^3+4xy^2(dy/dx))+(5y+5(dy/dx))=0$. The last term should be $5xdy/dx$

Comment: Corrected and got the answer 3, which is still apparently wrong

Answer (score 1):

When you differentiate y^3 you have to lower the 3 as a coefficient

Comment: Didn't I do that? I got dy/dx(4xy^2) instead of dy/dx(4xy^3)

Comment: but you have to multiply by 3

Comment: I don't get it, can you show me?

Comment: d/dx(y^3) = dy/dx *3* y^2   remember that d/dx (x^3) = 3x^2

Comment: I did this, and got the answer 51/4, which is apparently also incorrect :(

Comment: Oops! You are right, calculator fail on my end. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you perform the differentiation, the first step leads to $$(4y^3+12xy^2 \frac {dy}{dx})+(5y+5\frac {dy}{dx})=0$$ which leads to $$\frac {dy}{dx}=-\frac{4 y^3+5 y}{x \left(12 y^2+5\right)}$$ and at $(3,1)$ the value is the $-\frac {3}{17}$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $4xy^3 + 5xy = 27$. Differentiate implicitly to obtain $$\left(4y^3 + 12xy^2\frac{dy}{dx}\right) + \left(5y + 5x\frac{dy}{dx}\right) = 0.$$
Rearranging and factoring this, we find $$\frac{dy}{dx}\left(12xy^2 +5x\right)=-y(4y^2+5).$$ Then, assuming $\,\,x,y \in \mathbb{R} \,\,\, \text{and} \,\,\, 12xy^2+5x=x(12y^2+5)\neq0 \iff x\neq0$, we have (upon dividing both sides by this expression) $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{y(4y^2+5)}{x(12y^2+5)}.$$
It follows that, evaluating the expression for the derivative at $(3,1)$, we have $$\frac{dy}{dx}\biggr|_{(3,1)}=-\frac{9}{51}=-\frac{3}{17}.$$
This is the slope of the tangent line you were seeking.